# jupyter notebook not opening up in anaconda prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I wanted to activate my environment and change the directory and then launch notebook. But it shows me this error

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\anesh>jupyter-notebook
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\anesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe C:\Users\anesh\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py '
```

I tried updating anaconda navigator but still does not work. Can anyone please give me a solution for this?

Comment: check the local variable/path to the folder destination, windows process requires the correct path to work. Here is the official documentation for windows https://conda.io/docs/installation.html

Comment: I just wanted to change the directory and launch jupyter notebook from there. It worked till morning. But after sometime it shows me this error.